# Ocultar URL al pasar parametros C# MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cshtml, .netframework

me encontre con un problema, tengo un ecommerce web con ASP.NET, Net Framework y MVC, estoy en una pagina que es el resultado de una busqueda y al dar clic sobre algun producto de la lista nos debe redirigir a la pagina de detalle, el problema es que al momento de pasar hacia esa vista la URL queda expuesta con toda la informacion en la barra de navegacion, el codigo en la pagina de busqueda es el siguiente:

```
 <span class="name-product">

     <a href="@Url.Action("GetDataByProduct", "Details", new {
                      sku = part.sku,
                      partId = part.partId,
                      localInv = part.productInventory.ldcInventory,
                      name = part.name,
                      price = part.productPrice.price,
                      inventory = part.productInventory.localInventory,
                      multiplo = part.productInventory.minOrderQty,
                      description = part.description,
                      imageList = string.Join(";", part.imagesUrl)
                  })" title="Click para ver detalle" class="product-link">
         @part.name
     </a>
 </span>
```

Intente hacerlo mediante un form, enviando el formulario y recibiendolo en el controlador, funciona ya que es un metodo POST, el problema esta en que existe la persistencia de datos, por lo que al dar clic en un producto, regresar y dar clic en otro se mantiene la informacion del primero. Mi idea era hacerlo asi:

```
<form id="productForm" action="/Details/GetDataByProduct" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="partId" name="partId" value="@part.partId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="sku" name="sku" value="@part.sku" />
    <input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="@part.name" />
    <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="@part.productPrice.price" />
    <input type="hidden" id="inventory" name="inventory" value="@part.productInventory.localInventory" />
    <input type="hidden" id="multiplo" name="multiplo" value="@part.productInventory.minOrderQty" />
    <input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="@part.description" />
    <input type="hidden" id="foreignInv" name="foreignInv" value="@part.productInventory.ldcInventory" />
    <input type="hidden" id="imageList" name="imageList" value="@string.Join(";", part.imagesUrl)" />
</form>
```

Y luego con javascript solo enviarlo:

```
$(".product-link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#productForm").submit();
});
```

Espero puedan orientarme con la pregunta, gracias!

Comment: Si la pagina se llama GetDataByProduct, porque mandas todos los datos en lugar de solo el id?

Comment: Esos datos vienen de una peticion a una API al momento de buscar el producto, lo que quiero evitar al ir a la pagina de detalle es volver a hacer esa peticion, por lo que los datos que ya tengo los envio de esa manera, quiza este mal desde ahi, no se si haya otra manera para hacerlo

Comment: al dar click en otro, no deberias volver a llenar los campos ocultos? de paso, si estan en la pagina, estan.. que se vean o no en la url no te va a cambiar la ecuacion, porque estan en la pagina.. es mas, hasta los debes estar mostrando.. y si no los estas mostrando, entonces estas trayendo cosas de mas ;)

Comment: Claro los campos se vuelven a llenar, en si lo que me interesa es que la url no lleve toda esa información, esos datos los muestro en la pagina a donde los mando por que son parte de su composición pero quiero evitar mostrarlos en la url, no están de más por que todos se usan.

Comment: En la url debes enviar solo los datos necesarios para encontrar el item (generalmente lo(s) Id). En el servidor consultas por esas Id's y te traes los datos faltantes para generar la vista detalle. Mostrar datos en URL no supone ningún riesgo, incluso es todo lo contrario. Lo que si supone un riesgo es utilizar esas variables para renderizar una vista aun cuando esas variables se envíen por POST (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)